# "Non Zero Exit Status" R 3.0.1 'XML' and 'RCurl'

Tags: xml, linux, r, rcurl, install.packages

I am having a bit of trouble installing XML and RCurl on my Ubuntu machine 13.10. I performed all sudo update and upgrades today.

I am trying to use rattle for R. I am unable to install 'XML' which is required for the use of rattle. This is pretty much the same question that was asked [right here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13846311/non-zero-exit-status-error-downloading-xml-and-rcurl-r-pacakges) just a year later and a different OS.  Here are the error messages that I am getting back:

```
> install.packages("RCurl")
Installing package into ‘/home/steven/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.0’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
trying URL 'http://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/RCurl_1.95-4.1.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 870915 bytes (850 Kb)
opened URL
==================================================
downloaded 850 Kb

* installing *source* package ‘RCurl’ ...
** package ‘RCurl’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
checking for curl-config... no
Cannot find curl-config
ERROR: configuration failed for package ‘RCurl’
* removing ‘/home/steven/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.0/RCurl’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘RCurl’ had non-zero exit status

The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘/tmp/RtmpUwBkbS/downloaded_packages’
> install.packages("XML")
Installing package into ‘/home/steven/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.0’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
trying URL 'http://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/XML_3.98-1.1.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 1582216 bytes (1.5 Mb)
opened URL
==================================================
downloaded 1.5 Mb

* installing *source* package ‘XML’ ...
** package ‘XML’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
checking for gcc... gcc
checking for C compiler default output file name... 
rm: cannot remove 'a.out.dSYM': Is a directory
a.out
checking whether the C compiler works... yes
checking whether we are cross compiling... no
checking for suffix of executables... 
checking for suffix of object files... o
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes
checking whether gcc accepts -g... yes
checking for gcc option to accept ISO C89... none needed
checking how to run the C preprocessor... gcc -E
checking for sed... /bin/sed
checking for pkg-config... /usr/bin/pkg-config
checking for xml2-config... no
Cannot find xml2-config
ERROR: configuration failed for package ‘XML’
* removing ‘/home/steven/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.0/XML’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘XML’ had non-zero exit status

The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘/tmp/RtmpUwBkbS/downloaded_packages’
```

Not too sure on how to proceed from here.

Comment: Have you installed curl and xml on linux. Run `sudo apt-get install libcurl4-openssl-dev` and `sudo apt-get install libxml2-dev`.

Comment: It's important to install the development libraries for R. You may not have chose that option (and you chose to install an outdated version, to boot.)

Comment: @jdharrison I have not tried those commands, I'll give them a try when I get home tonight.

Comment: @IShouldBuyABoat I did not know I needed to install the dev libraries for R. I installed 3.0.1 when I upgraded Ubuntu from 13.04 to 13.01, I simply installed from the Software Center.

Comment: @jdharrison that solved the problem, so you can list it as the answer and I will accept it, thank you.

Answer (score 133, accepted):

To install curl and xml on Ubuntu. Run

```
sudo apt-get install libcurl4-openssl-dev libxml2-dev
```

The error messages on package install in R indicate that the curl and xml libraries are not present or cannot be found.

Comment: or `libcurl4-gnutls-dev` will work as an alternative to `libcurl4-openssl-dev`. See also http://askubuntu.com/a/428379/17060

Comment: I am working in WSL running R on Ubuntu 16.04; this command at bash prompt has resolved my issue `apt-get install libssl-dev`

Answer (score 29):

In CentOS 6+ you can do it using

```
sudo yum -y install curl
sudo yum -y install libcurl libcurl-devel
sudo yum -y install libxml2 libxml2-devel
```

Comment: You also need `sudo yum -y install libxml2 libxml2-devel`

Comment: The first two commands sufficed for me when I was installing "h2o"

Answer (score 2):

For those who can't install using `yum` or `apt-get`, I share my experience:

I installed `libcurl-openssl-dev` myself by downloading the source code and compiling. I still ran into the `Cannot find curl-config` problem though...I didn't know what to do until looking at RCurl source code and seeing a `CURL_CONFIG` environment variable being referenced. I tried setting this myself in my `.bashrc` and it seems to have worked:

`export CURL_CONFIG=~/my/libcurl/curl-config`

Answer (score 0):

for ubuntu 18.05 sometimes repository having issues run as per below

## add below repository in sudoedited line

### deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security main

```
sudoedit /etc/apt/sources.list 
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install libcurl4-openssl-dev --fix-broken
sudo apt-get install libcurl4-openssl-dev libxml2-dev
```

---

fix package name