# Can not install Rcurl package on ubuntu, do I need curl configuration ? [R]

Tags: r, ubuntu, curl, rcurl

I am trying to install `Rcurl` package in R on Ubuntu but I get this error. Can anyone know what should I do to install this package properly? Do I need curl configuration in Terminal?

```
> install.packages("RCurl")
Installing package into ‘/home/marcin/R/i686-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.1’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
próbowanie adresu URL 'http://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/RCurl_1.95-4.3.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 879143 bytes (858 Kb)
otwarty adres URL
==================================================
downloaded 858 Kb

* installing *source* package ‘RCurl’ ...
** pakiet ‘RCurl’ został pomyślnie rozpakowany oraz sumy MD5 zostały sprawdzone
checking for curl-config... no
Cannot find curl-config
ERROR: configuration failed for package ‘RCurl’
* removing ‘/home/marcin/R/i686-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.1/RCurl’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘RCurl’ had non-zero exit status

The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘/tmp/Rtmp5oxaeI/downloaded_packages’
```

Comment: It requires the -dev package of the library. Use `sudo apt-get install libcurl4-gnutls-dev` or `sudo apt-get install libcurl4-openssl-dev`

Comment: Eh, was about to say if http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20671814/non-zero-exit-status-r-3-0-1-xml-and-rcurl doesn't help.