# Why some R packages can't be installed

Tags: r, linux, package, ubuntu-16.04, imputets

I've been using R for a while and everything was normal when installing packages. Recently, I upgraded R on my `Ubuntu 16.04` from `3.4.4` to `4.0.2` and then I tried to install the package `imputeTS` as

```
> install.packages("imputeTS")
Installing package into ‘/home/.../R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.0’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
also installing the dependencies ‘png’, ‘gridtext’, ‘ggtext’

trying URL 'https://cloud.r-project.org/src/contrib/png_0.1-7.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 24990 bytes (24 KB)
==================================================
downloaded 24 KB

trying URL 'https://cloud.r-project.org/src/contrib/gridtext_0.1.1.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 441462 bytes (431 KB)
==================================================
downloaded 431 KB

trying URL 'https://cloud.r-project.org/src/contrib/ggtext_0.1.0.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 1849875 bytes (1.8 MB)
==================================================
downloaded 1.8 MB

trying URL 'https://cloud.r-project.org/src/contrib/imputeTS_3.1.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 3015320 bytes (2.9 MB)
==================================================
downloaded 2.9 MB

* installing *source* package ‘png’ ...
** package ‘png’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** using staged installation
** libs
gcc -std=gnu99 -I"/usr/share/R/include" -DNDEBUG      `libpng-config --cflags` -fpic  -g -O2 -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g  -c read.c -o read.o
gcc -std=gnu99 -I"/usr/share/R/include" -DNDEBUG      `libpng-config --cflags` -fpic  -g -O2 -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g  -c write.c -o write.o
gcc -std=gnu99 -shared -L/usr/lib/R/lib -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-z,relro -o png.so read.o write.o -L/home/.../anaconda/lib -lpng16 -lm -lz -lm -L/usr/lib/R/lib -lR
installing to /home/.../R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.0/00LOCK-png/00new/png/libs
** R
** inst
** byte-compile and prepare package for lazy loading
** help
*** installing help indices
** building package indices
** testing if installed package can be loaded from temporary location
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘png’ in dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...):
 unable to load shared object '/home/.../R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.0/00LOCK-png/00new/png/libs/png.so':
  libpng16.so.16: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
Error: loading failed
Execution halted
ERROR: loading failed
* removing ‘/home/.../R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.0/png’
ERROR: dependency ‘png’ is not available for package ‘gridtext’
* removing ‘/home/.../R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.0/gridtext’
ERROR: dependency ‘gridtext’ is not available for package ‘ggtext’
* removing ‘/home/.../R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.0/ggtext’
ERROR: dependency ‘ggtext’ is not available for package ‘imputeTS’
* removing ‘/home/.../R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.0/imputeTS’

The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘/tmp/RtmpZubgYt/downloaded_packages’
Warning messages:
1: In install.packages("imputeTS") :
  installation of package ‘png’ had non-zero exit status
2: In install.packages("imputeTS") :
  installation of package ‘gridtext’ had non-zero exit status
3: In install.packages("imputeTS") :
  installation of package ‘ggtext’ had non-zero exit status
4: In install.packages("imputeTS") :
  installation of package ‘imputeTS’ had non-zero exit status
```

Then

```
> library(imputeTS)
Error in library(imputeTS) : there is no package called ‘imputeTS’
```

I tried to install the same package as `install.packages("imputeTS", dependencies = TRUE)` but this gave me the same result  `installation of package ‘imputeTS’ had non-zero exit status`

Following, I tried to install the packages `Hmisc` and `mice`. The same result was for the first package where as `mice` was installed successfully!

Two more comments, the first is this statement `(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)` started to appear just after upgrading R. The second, I am not sure if related, is that  there is no space on my linux!

So how could I install the needed packages successfuly?

Comment: relevant / possible duplicate : https://stackoverflow.com/q/20671814/4137985

Comment: Thanks @Cath for the link. So, to install the packages imputeTS and Hmisc, how should I fill the code ' sudo apt-get install lib????.-openssl-dev lib????-dev '

Comment: @Cath Additionally, Would you please why the library path changed once I upgraded R or if there is a relation ?

Comment: See this [AskUbuntu post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/701246/libpng16-so-16-not-found-how-to-get-it) about the installation of `libpng16.so.16`.

Comment: As for `lib`, you can set it with `install.packages("pkgname", lib = path/to/lib)`. Or you can make it permanent by finding file `Rprofile.site` and editing it. What does `.libPaths()` return?

Comment: Thanks @RuiBarradas for your comment. .libPaths() returns 

[1] "/home/.../R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.0"

[2] "/usr/local/lib/R/site-library"                      

[3] "/usr/lib/R/site-library"                            

[4] "/usr/lib/R/library" 

But I've never changed the path before or after upgrading R.This  (as ‘lib’ is unspecified) started to appear after upgrading. How can I solve this issue?

Comment: I would do `install.packages("pkgname", lib = .libPath()[2])` in order to have all packages in the same library, independent of the R version. Other directories could be 3 and 4 but not `.libPaths()[1]`. You can set this in your `Rprofile.site` file with `.libPaths(c("/usr/local/lib/R/site-library", "/usr/lib/R/site-library", "/usr/lib/R/library" ))`.

Comment: Thanks @RuiBarradas. The problem is solved using the link you added! I just did `(sudo apt-get install libpng16-16)` before installing the packages and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

Just a wrap up that people can find the correct answer given in the comments better and understand the error messages

**This is no problem related specifically to the `imputeTS` package.**

This can be seen in this part of the error message

> Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘png’ in dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...):
> unable to load shared object '/home/.../R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.0/00LOCK-png/00new/png/libs/png.so':
> libpng16.so.16: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

The error actually occurs while trying to install the `png` package.

How is this related to the `imputeTS` package?

You can see this here:

> ERROR: loading failed
>
> - removing ‘/home/.../R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.0/png’
>   ERROR: dependency ‘png’ is not available for package ‘gridtext’
> - removing ‘/home/.../R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.0/gridtext’
>   ERROR: dependency ‘gridtext’ is not available for package ‘ggtext’
> - removing ‘/home/.../R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.0/ggtext’
>   ERROR: dependency ‘ggtext’ is not available for package ‘imputeTS’
> - removing ‘/home/.../R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.0/imputeTS’

R packages build on each other and import functions of other packages. In this case imputeTS imports ggtext, which imports gridtext, which imports png.

So quite a sequence of dependencies and if installation of `png` fails, this affects all the other packages.

Luckily this part of the error message also gives a hint, what could be wrong:

> unable to load shared object '/home/.../R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.0/00LOCK-png/00new/png/libs/png.so':
> libpng16.so.16: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

There is a library missing on which the `png` package itself depends on. Without this library the installation of `png` will fail and cause all these mentioned issues.

So just install the library like this:

```
sudo apt-get install libpng16-16
```